# react-native, realm: how to trigger re-render in another tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, realm

how is it possible (without the use of redux) to trigger an re-render in another tab?

I am using:

- react-native-navigation: "^1.1.486"
- realm": "^2.16.1"

Basically in Screen A a couple of functions write data into the realm database. In Screen B the view remains the same (based on the old database values) unless i do manual re-render on the device via a button for instance.

How can i trigger the re-rendering in Screen B depending on write functions to realm in Screen A ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else is stumbling also to this question. I found a solution for react-native-navigation:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));
}

onNavigatorEvent(event) {
    if (event.id === 'bottomTabSelected') {
      this.forceUpdate()
    }

  }
```